# How to open, edit, and save file on USB connected Android phone via notebook/desktop

Tags: usb-connection-mode, files, editing

Personally I do a lot with VBA in Excel and like it to explore various software to find the one that fits my needs best. I am a friend of proper data management, e.g. having photos taken at hand based on keyword management. Since I have my phone always with me, I have various lists in a text editor app. E.g. next needed maintenance at the car, grocery shopping list or a list of places I discover in my hometown. Sometimes I want to read and edit these lists at my notebook using Wordpad.

So I connect my phone with a USB cable, select the folder on the internal phone memory and see all the files as proper .txt.
**But:** On my notebook when right-clicking a file, I can select 'open with' (there I select 'Wordpad'). But the files in the internal phone memory do not show this option on right-click.

If I copy the file to my computer, it works properly. If I have Wordpad open and select a file via 'file open' from the phone, then it opens properly in 'Wordpad', **but** automatically with an [1] in the file name. Obviously, write-protected. If I want to save any edits, I cannot save that back to the phone in the same file. Only to my computer and then copy back to my phone.

**My setting:** Samsung Galaxy A3 2017 with Android Nougat. Windows 7 Notebook.

**My question:** How can I enable opening a text file with Wordpad (solved with 'file open'), edit, and save the edits directly with the file on the phone when USB is connected? Ideally getting also the 'open with' option when right-clicking a file on the phone. Do I need to change any USB access option on my phone permanently? I searched via Google in various word combinations but did not find a helpful post.

Answer (score 1):

The [MTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) used between phone and PC does not support editing. MTP is a very simple protocol that allows only listing files/folders including properties, download a file from the phone, upload a file to the phone and delete a file/folder. Additionally while one operation is ongoing no other operation can be performed.

Originally MTP was designed for very simple devices like early photo cameras without much CPU or RAM.

As editing is not supported you can only simulate it by downloading the file to the PC, edit and and then upload it back to the phone. The download part is integrated into Windows, but the upload part seems to be missing.

Also important (but Windows specific) is that MTP devices are shown in the Windows Explorer but can not be accessed by applications by a path like `F:\`. Therefore the Open With menu is totally different.